# некорректная работа счетчика

Tags: javascript, html

Хола, друзья!
У меня сейчас дата отъезда прибавляется к незаданной дате приезда. А если дату приезда задать, то это ничего не меняет и дата отъезда всё равно считается по-своему.
Как мне реализовать, что бы поле "дата отъезда" не жило само по себе и дружило с полем "дата приезда"?

```js
(function() {

  var arrivalDate = new Date();
  var departureDate = new Date();
  var arrival = document.querySelector("#date-arrival");
  arrival.value = dateToString(arrivalDate);

  var duration = document.querySelector("#days-stay");
  var departure = document.querySelector("#date-departure");
  departureDate.setDate(departureDate.getDate() + Number(duration.value) - 1);
  departure.value = dateToString(departureDate);

  var plusDay = document.querySelector("#days-plus");
  var minusDay = document.querySelector("#days-minus");
  var durationDays = document.querySelector("#days-stay");

  plusDay.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    changeValue(durationDays, true);
    departureDate.setDate(departureDate.getDate() + Number(1));
    departure.value = dateToString(departureDate);
  });

  minusDay.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (durationDays.value > 1) {
      changeValue(durationDays, false);
      departureDate.setDate(departureDate.getDate() - 1);
      departure.value = dateToString(departureDate);
    }
  });

  function dateToString(temp) {
    return ("0" + temp.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + ("0" + Number(temp.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "." + temp.getFullYear()
  }

  function changeValue(input, operation) {
    if (isNaN(input.value)) {
      input.value = 0;
    }
    if (operation) {
      input.value++;
    } else {
      input.value--;
      if (input.value < 0) {
        input.value = 0;
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="form__block">
  <div class="form__block-heading">
    <h2 class="form__block-title">Даты вашей поездки:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form__row  clearfix">
    <div class="form__input-block">
      <label class="form__label" for="date-arrival">
        Дата приезда:*
      </label>
      <input class="form__input-text" id="date-arrival" type="text" name="date-arrival">
    </div>
    <div class="form__input-block">
      <label class="form__label" for="days-stay">
        Дней пребывания:*
      </label>
      <div class="form__count-block">
        <button class="form__input-enter form__input-enter--minus" id="days-minus" type="button">-</button>
        <div class="form__input-description form__input-description-day">
          <!-- тут псевдокласс дн. -->
          <input class="form__input-text" id="days-stay" type="number" name="days-stay" value="14">
        </div>
        <button class="form__input-enter form__input-enter--plus" id="days-plus" type="button">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__input-block">
      <label class="form__label" for="date-departure">
        Дата отъезда:*
      </label>
      <input class="form__output" id="date-departure" type="text" name="date-departure" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно повесить обработчик `change` на `$("#date-arrival")`, который будет тоже обновлять дату отъезда.

А вообще, не стоит изобретать все эти элементы форм с плюсами/минусами/вводом дат - в HTML5 они итак есть. Я бы вашу форму сделал примерно так:

```js
(function () {
  var updateDeparture = function () {
    var 
      date = $('#arrival')[0].valueAsDate,
      days = parseInt($('#days').val());

    if (date) {
      date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      $('#departure')[0].valueAsDate = date;
    }
  };
  
  $('#arrival')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
  updateDeparture();
  
  $('#arrival').change(updateDeparture);
  $('#days').change(updateDeparture);
}.call(this));
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
}

input {
  width: 60%;
}

div {
  padding: 2pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Даты вашей поездки:</h2>

<div>
  <label for="arrivial">Прибытие:</label>
  <input name="arrival" id="arrival" type="date" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="days">Дней:</label>
  <input name="days" id="days" type="number" min="1" value="14" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="departure">Отъезд:</label>
  <input name="departure" id="departure" type="date" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А без JQ будет работать?

Comment: @kaktyc, мой код - нет, там для выбора элементов он используется. Впрочем, зависимость от jQuery там убирается тривально - заменой `$(...)[0]` на `document.querySelector(...)`, да заменой `$(...).change(updateDeparture)` на `document.querySelector(...).addEventListener('change', updateDeparture)`